# Convert string to DateTime value

Tags: apex

How can i convert this string  t

> 10/04/2017 16:10:43

to a DateTime value?

DateTime.Parse() didn't work.

Comment: As long as you are sure that forman will be the same, you can split by space first, then split by "/" and assign date from first part, and then split by ":" and assign time from second part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter for `Datetime.parse(datetimeString)` is interpreted as date string in the current user's locale so you need to ensure this string value is in the correct locale format.

**Example taken from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm):**

```java
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
String myDtString = dt.format();
system.assertEquals(myDtString, '10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

> This example uses parse to create a Datetime from a date passed in as a string and that is formatted for the English (United States) locale. You may need to change the format of the date string if you have a different locale.

**Further reading:**

- [Datetime Class reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)